# Omitting repeated text with 

Tags: usage

I remember when I was studying in China a teacher of mine said you could omit a word under the same word using the character/symbol . Coincidentally I bumped into it yesterday and remembered that. But I'm not sure if this is correct and if it's really ***this*** character. For example:

> 中国 很 大。
>    ....  很 漂亮。  (omitting 中国)
>    ....  在 亚洲。  (omitting 中国)

**Questions:**
1 - Does  really have this function?
2 - Does  have a name?

Thanks

Comment: It's more likely to be「[々](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%80%85)」than「」.「々」is far more common in Japanese rather than Chinese, and in both languages its usage is more commonly seen as in [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/can-%E4%B8%8A-always-be-used-like-english-i-e-same-as-above/28527).

Comment: It is likely that the correct character is not shown properly and thus substituted by a square.

Comment: @zyy I believe that that’s only on your side. It displays fine on my computer.

Comment: @user3306356 Then it seem like you are the only one who could answer this question correctly.

Comment: @zyy droooze has already written a good answer in the post he linked above - this might even be a duplicate.

Comment: @user3306356 not quite a duplicate - several places say that「々」is used as a substitute for「等」(as in 等等) or「～」as in [the usage at zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/20/js/7B49.htm), which matches the OP's description. The linked question only describes character repetition within one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) yes, it represent what is from the above!
But in formal writing, Like journals or school articles or official documents from the lawyers. we are not allow this kind of writing. But in private conversations, email or when professor write on the black board. People understand that this is used to denote the words in the sentence above it.
2) no