# Typing iteration (repetition) symbols

Tags: punctuation

Is there a convention for typing the 匕-like iteration symbol seen here (several times near the center of the page, excluding the header)?

This is one of five iteration symbols I've come across in Hokkien & Taiwanese texts. The others are:

〻 (dedicated Unicode node, but the representation in some fonts leaves much to be desired)

〱

⺀

々

It seems that the other four symbols have Unicode representation. Only the 匕-like one — typically more like ヒ — doesn't seem to. (Is that because it's regional? Does anybody know if it occurs outside the Hokkien-Teochew or Formosa Strait region?) Did it evolve from (卑履切) 匕?

Comment: Does this: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/28438/4136 answer your question?

Comment: I won't say these types of symbols have never been used in Chinese, but they are not a normal thing to use. I wouldn't be suprised if many don't know them at all-- I only recognize some of them from Japanese. Although I haven't seen it maybe in casual handwriting? Keep in mind, Japanese only uses Chinese characters for a part of their writing system. It makes sense to have a character similar to the simpler forms of their system to speed up writing. In chinese, it doesn't really make sense to specially skip one single character of eight strokes, just to immediately write another twenty charact

Comment: Thank you, @Mou某. That seems to be the extent of what anybody knows about this topic.

Comment: I remember seeing this symbol -&gt;々occasionally in handwritings when I was little, but it has been largely disappeared. My parents never used it. The time saved by writing 々 instead of, say, 人、日 or 山 (or some other characters used consecutively) is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, they are deprecated symbols(not characters) and no more recommended to use in standard Chinese. They may still occur in some calligraphy work or in private notes.

https://zi.tools/ is a very good website to search the encodings, usages and other miscs for all kinds of logograms. For example, https://zi.tools/zi/%E3%80%85

Avoid using them (in daily life) unless necessary (for academic reason or so). If you mean to type it, there is a very useful input method called [Rime](https://rime.im/) which is highly customizable.

Comment: That is an excellent website. And I've never heard of Rime. Thanks.
　
Standard Chinese was the farthest thing from my mind, actually.

Comment: @KIRINPUTRA if you find my answer helpful, don't hesitate to upvote it (as well as other answers), this will draw more attenion of the community to this very question and you may likely get more help.